# Stating that the above terms are "open to discussion"

Tags: business-japanese

I'm writing a business message that outlines a proposed resolution to an issue/dispute - e.g. Party A pays Party B $X, Party B pays Party C $Y and does this and that.

I want to end the message saying that the above terms are tentative, and if the recipient (the other business party) has a better idea, they are free to come up with a suggestion. How can I express this?

> 以上の取り決めは、もしかしたら (a better idea)、こちら側と相談できます。

This is in a business setting, so I would like it to be as formal as possible.

Comment: I think the question is just too vague to make specific suggestions. 諸条件はご相談いただけます may work. It means *the conditions are open to negotiation*.

Comment: honestly I'd take that as an answer, I forgot the いただけます construct existed. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can phrase your message in Japanese as follows:

以上の提案に関しましては、暫定的なものでございます。貴社により良いご提案がございましたら、是非お知らせください。当社としても、貴社のご意見を拝聴し、共に最適な解決策を模索したいと考えております。

This translates to:

"The above proposal is tentative. Should your company have a better suggestion, please do not hesitate to inform us. We are eager to hear your opinions and together seek the most suitable resolution."

This wording maintains a formal tone and shows respect for the other party's input, while clearly stating that the terms are provisional and open for discussion.